# Controller not defined when use action Helper

Tags: php, laravel, url-routing, laravel-5.3

I have the controller@method name in a variable, and I want to get url of this controller, so I use `action()` Helper in Laravel, but I get this error:

```
InvalidArgumentException in UrlGenerator.php line 605:
Action App\Http\Controllers\Dashboard\Users\UserController@index not defined.
```

This is my `route/web.php` :

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth','nav'], 'prefix' => 'dashboard', 'namespace' => 'dashboard'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'DashboardController@index')->name('dashboard');

    Route::group(['prefix' => 'users', 'namespace' => 'users'], function () {
        Route::get('/list', 'UserController@index');
    });
});
```

and in variable I store this string :

```
Dashboard\Users\UserController@index
```

What is the problem ?

**UPDATE :**

I use `action()` Helper in middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\Models\User\Nav;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

class NavMenu
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  \Closure $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        ...
        $sample = $this->createNavigation();
        ...
        return $next($request);
    }

    public function createNavigation()
    {
        ...
        $url = action('Dashboard\Users\UserController@index');
        ...

        return $url;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you please explain where are you using the action helper?

Comment: @YohananBaruchel I use in middleware, I updated my question

Comment: Sorry I can't see the namespace of those controllers, but as I can see from the routes file, the name of the namespaces is lowercase and not uppercase as you passed it to the action helper.. that means that the action helper should receive 'dashboard\users\UserController@index' instead of 'Dashboard\Users\UserController@index'